# Computing Powersets in C#

Tags: java, c#

I tried to convert the below **Java** code into **C#**. The Java code *works fine* but C# code is *not returning the powersets*. Am I missing something?

**Java Code**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(1);
    list.add(2);
    list.add(3);

    List<List<Integer>> subsets = new ArrayList<>();

    System.out.println(generateSubsets(
      0, 
      list.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray(), 
      new ArrayList<Integer>(), 
      subsets));
}

static List<List<Integer>> generateSubsets(
    int index, 
    int[] nums, 
    List<Integer> current, 
    List<List<Integer>> subsets){
    
    subsets.add(new ArrayList<>(current));
    
    for(int i = index; i < nums.length; i++){
        current.add(nums[i]);
        generateSubsets(i + 1, nums,current, subsets);
        current.remove(current.size() - 1);
    }

    return subsets;
}
```

**C# Code**

```
static List<List<Integer>> generateSubsets(
    int index, 
    int[] nums, 
    List<Integer> current, 
    List<List<Integer>> subsets) {
    
    subsets.add(new List(current));

    for (int i = index; (i < nums.length); i++) {
        current.add(nums[i]);
        generateSubsets((i + 1), nums, current, subsets);
        current.remove((current.size() - 1));
    }
    
    return subsets;
}
```

**Expected Output**

```
[[], [1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 3], [2], [2, 3], [3]]
```

Comment: *"Am I missing something?"* Input sample with expected output. Something reproducible

Comment: Thanks @Cid. I've added both

Comment: I don't know Java well enough to know the properties on the List object, but based on what your code looks like it is trying to do, I'd say you need to change in the C# current.size() to current.Count.

Comment: You should start by making this code actually compile...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's seems it'll be *easier* to create `generateSubsets` *from scratch* then *convert* the routine from Java. We can implement the method with a help of *Linq*:

```
using System.Linq;

...

private static List<List<T>> generateSubsets<T>(List<T> source) {
  return Enumerable
    .Range(0, 1 << source.Count)
    .Select(index => Enumerable
      .Range(0, source.Count)
      .Where(i => (index & (1 << i)) != 0)
      .Select(i => source[i])
      .ToList())
    .ToList(); 
}
```

The idea which is behind the code is to generate all *masks* `[0 .. 2**Count)` and then take subset items according each mask:

```
000....000 - empty set (no items)
000....001 - set with 1st item only
000....010 - set with 2nd item only
000....011 - set with 1st and 2nd items
000....100 - set with 3d item only
..........
111....110 - set with all items except 1st one
111....111 - set with all items
```

**Demo:**

```
public static void Main(String[] args) {
  List<int> list = new List<int>() {
    1, 2, 3,
  };

  var subsets = generateSubsets(list); 

  Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, subsets
    .Select(s => $"[{string.Join(", ", s)}]")));

  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

**Outcome:**

```
[]
[1]
[2]
[1, 2]
[3]
[1, 3]
[2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
```