# How to generate powersets with a maximum size in C#?

Tags: c#, combinations, powerset

I am trying to generate all powersets from a given list within a limit of given maximum size. I've found some great answers for how to generate powersets in general and admire the solution using bitmaps found here [All Possible Combinations of a list of Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802822/all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-of-values) or here [Computing Powersets in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65522722/computing-powersets-in-c-sharp).

Is there a way to generate sets with a maximum size of 'maxSize' numbers in one set? E.g. my input is {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, but I only want results with 3 or less items. Is it possible to do within the one command? I have found a solution where I iterate over all items of the result, but this is quite inefficient for large inputs with smaller maxSize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy with recursion:

```
static public IEnumerable<List<int>> FindAllCombos(List<int> list, int maxSize, int minIndex = 0)
{
    yield return new List<int>();
    if (maxSize > 0)
        for (int i = minIndex; i < list.Count; i++)
            foreach (var set in FindAllCombos(list, maxSize - 1, i + 1))
            {
                set.Add(list[i]);
                yield return set;
            }
}
```

Note that the elements of the output sets will here be in the reverse order.

Comment: Thank you, this does exactly what I want! I don't care about the order of the elements within the set, so that's fine. The only thing I had to fix was to remove the first (empty) element of the list, which I simply did after the method terminated.